# tag searching with many to many fields in php

Tags: php, jquery, search, tagging

i'm trying to do a search engine for a briefing system.

I'm using a many to many relationship style setup with 3 databases representing the relationships.

comms_briefings is where the data is stored for the briefings
search_tags is where the tags are stored 
briefings_tags is where the relationship is formed

i have [this code](http://pastie.org/627245) already which **ALMOST** perfect however, for some reason it returns the same row in the database multiple times if a tag appears more than once in the briefing.

eg if user searchs for

> $ "complx enquiries"

the system will return any row that has the tag complx and enquiries twice as there are two matching tags. I want the results to be ordered desc with the row that gets the most results first and only to appear once.

any ideas? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do:

```
function searchTags($tags) {

    $tags = explode(' ', $tags);
    $tagIds = array();

    foreach($tags as $key) {
        $sql = mysql_query("SELECT `id` FROM `search_tags` WHERE `tag` = '".$key."'");
        while($r=mysql_fetch_object($sql))
            $tagIds[] = $r->id;
    }

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT comms_briefings.*, COUNT(*) AS num
        FROM comms_briefings, briefings_tags
        WHERE briefings_tags.tag_id IN ('" . implode("','", $tagIds) ."') AND briefings_tags.briefing_id = comms_briefings.id
            GROUP BY comms_briefines.id
        ORDER BY num DESC, `created` DESC"); 

    while($r = mysql_fetch_object($query)) {

        $summation = preg_replace('^(.*)\n(.*)^', '$1\\n$2', $r->summation);
        $summation = preg_replace('/[\r]+/', '', $summation);

        echo '<li class="message unread" id="msg-'.$r->id.'">';
        echo '<h3><a href="">'.$r->title.'</a></h3>';
        echo '<ul class="details">
                <li><span>Importance:</span> '.$r->importance.'</li>
                <li><span>Date:</span> '.$r->created.'</li>
                <li><span>Summary:</span> '.$summation.'</li>
             </ul>
             <div class="clr"></div>
             </li>';
    }
}
```

All the tagIds are pulled into an array first, then you do a single query on the briefings, grouping by id.

Comment: looks good greg, however it comes back with an error with that Warning: mysql_fetch_object(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/sdg/classes/messages.classes.php on line 17

which is the while statement

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'COUNT(*) AS num WHERE `briefings_tags.tag_id` IN ('1,2,5') AND `briefing' at line 2

Comment: Hmmm did you copy all the quotes? It should look like IN ('1', '2', '5')